# How to Pass Parameters to bcp in a stored procedure in SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have to export from code (C#), using a stored procedure (in SQL Server 2017) some file blob inside a database (binary format) and save them in a directory of the server, that is running a web application. I'm using BCP command inside a stored procedure. I have problems when I try to insert parameters in stored procedure.

This stored procedure without parameters is running well; where I can extract a file with idDoc=20167 and I name it 'tt1.pdf' in the directory 'e\temp\sql2017'

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spDocumentiBCP_1]
AS
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(1000)

    SET @sql = 'BCP "SELECT binario FROM Database1.dbo.TbDocumentibin 
                     WHERE idDoc=20167" 
                     QUERYOUT e:\temp\sql2017\tt1.pdf -T -f e:\TEMP\sql2017\blob1.fmt -S PCNAME\sql2017 ' 

    EXEC master.dbo.xp_CmdShell @sql 
END
```

I have tried to insert parameters in stored procedure but I get errors.

This is an example of the stored procedure I need, but I don't know how to use parameters in this case, inside BCP :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spDocumentiBCP_1]
    (@idDoc INT,
     @filename VARCHAR(150))
AS
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(500)
    SET @sql = 'BCP "SELECT binario FROM Database.dbo.TbDocumentibin where idDoc=@idDoc" 
QUERYOUT e:\temp\sql2017\@nomefile -T -f 
e:\TEMP\sql2017\blob1.fmt -S 
PCNAME\sql2017 ' 

    EXEC master.dbo.xp_CmdShell @sql 
END
```

I should export file-blob from a db and save them in a selected directory (on server who is running the web application) with a specific name. The problem now is use the parameters inside the stored procedure with BCP command.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
create procedure [dbo].[spDocumentiBCP_1] ( 
   @idDoc int, 
   @filename varchar(150)
)      
AS
BEGIN

Declare @sql varchar(500) 
set @sql = 'BCP "SELECT binario FROM Database.dbo.TbDocumentibin 
where idDoc=" ' + @idDoc + ' "QUERYOUT e:\temp\sql2017" ' + @filename + ' " -T -f e:\TEMP\sql2017\blob1.fmt -S PCNAME\sql2017" ' 

EXEC master.dbo.xp_CmdShell @sql 

END
```

Please note that there **should not** be a space between the `"` and `'` I bring the space to make the code clearer. The actual code should be like `"' + @idDoc +'"`

Comment: With this store procedure I have this error :                                                             
 Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Procedure dbo.spDocumentiBCP_5, Line 13 [Batch Start Line 2]
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'BCP "SELECT binario FROM Database.dbo.TbDocumentibin 
where idDoc=" ' to data type int.

Comment: I mean, the error comes out when I run the store procedure. I have tryed now this store procedure :